# Expected a quoted string (position:DOCDECL @1:50 in java.io.StringReader@4327b040) - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, rss

I am currently making an rss feed reading application for the android platform, it works for some RSS feeds; but not for others. IN particular, it does not work for any 'sky' hosted RSS feeds; but I am not sure why, whenever I try and use an RSS feed from the sky website, I just get the above error message.

RSS feeds like this for example:

http://www.skysports.com/rss/0,20514,11661,00.xml

I am not sure whether or not it is something to do with my XML parse I am using?

Could someone please point me in the right direction as to where I am going wrong?

Thanks.

My Feed page:

```
package com.example.directrssread;


import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import com.example.directrssread.Feed2.LongOperation;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Feed1 extends ListFragment{

    String[] URL = new String[3];
    int count = 0;
    String currURL = "";
    View mView;
     AdView adView = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    //Map<Date, ArrayList> menuItems = new TreeMap<Date, ArrayList>();
    Map<Date, ArrayList> sortedMap = null;
    ProgressDialog progress;

    //ProgressDialog.Builder builder;
    // final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog((ViewPagerFragmentActivity)getActivity());
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
    static final String KEY_LINK = "link";
    static final String KEY_PUBDATE = "pubDate";
    static final String KEY_PUBTIME = "pubDate";
    ListView lv = null;//getListView();

     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {


         Log.e("Feed1", "Feed1");
         menuItems.removeAll(menuItems);
         //lv = getListView();



         mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed1, container, false);
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed1, container, false);

        }

     public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         //menuItems.removeAll(menuItems);
         count = 0;     
          //rssRun();   
         lv = getListView();
         new LongOperation().execute();
          Log.e("Count", String.valueOf(menuItems.size())); 


         super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

         }

     public void rssRun()
     {

         Log.e("FEED1", "Running feed1");
         boolean runSubstring = true;
                            URL[0] = "http://www.football365.com/premier-league/rss";
            URL[1] = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/sport/0/football/rss.xml?edition=uk";
            URL[2] = "http://www.skysports.com/rss/0,20514,11661,00.xml";

            //URL[3] = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/sport/0/football/rss.xml?edition=uk";
            for (int f= 0;f < URL.length;f++)
            {

            try{
                 //Log.e("TEst1", "TEst");

            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL[f]); // getting XML
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
            Log.e("HERE", "HERE");
            //Log.e("XML", xml);

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
            //Log.e("NODELIST", nl.toString());
            // looping through all item nodes <item>

            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                if (doc!=null)
                {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    currURL = "Football365";
                }
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    currURL = "BBC Sport";
                }
                if (count == 2)
                {
                    //currURL = "SkySports";
                }

                //map.remove(map);

                map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                //Get the title of the article.
                map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                //Get the description of the article.
                map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
                //Get the source e.g ' Football365'.
                //String pubDate = parser.getValue(e, KEY_PUBDATE);
                String pubDate = parser.getValue(e, KEY_PUBDATE);
                //Parse the date and time from the main strings.
                //Chop off the un-wanted parts.
                //Bring them back together in one string.
                String pubTime = pubDate.substring(17, pubDate.length());
                String pubDateFormat = "";
                pubTime = pubTime.substring(0, 5);
                map.put(KEY_PUBDATE, pubTime);  

                pubDateFormat = pubDate.substring(0, 22);
                pubDate = pubDate.substring(0, 16);

                pubDate = pubDate + " " + pubTime;


                SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");
                Date date = dateFormatter.parse(pubDateFormat);
                dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                //Log.e("DATE", dateFormatter.format(date));
                //Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
                //String currDate
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                String currDate = sdf.format(new Date());
                //Log.e("CURRENT DATE", currDate);
                //System.out.println(dateFormatter.format(date));
                //System.out.println(sdf2.format(date));

                //Log.e("TITLE", )      
                map.put(KEY_TITLE, currURL + " - " + pubDate);          
                //Add the link.
                map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK));
                //Get the publish date.
                //map.put(KEY_PUBDATE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PUBDATE));
                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                //10
                //if (dateFormatter.format(date) == currDate)
//              if (dateFormatter.format(date).substring(0, 10) == currDate.substring(0, 10))
                //String  input = EditTextinput.getText().toString();
                //input = input.replace(" ", "");
                currDate = currDate.replace(" ", "");
                String rssDate = dateFormatter.format(date).replace(" ", "");
                Date dt1 = dateFormatter.parse(currDate);
                Date dt2 = dateFormatter.parse(rssDate);
                //Log.e("TRIM CURR", currDate);
                //Log.e("RSSDATE", rssDate);
                //if (rssDate == currDate)
                if (dt1.compareTo(dt2)==0)//== currDate)
                {
                    menuItems.add(map);
                    Collections.sort(menuItems, new MapComparator(KEY_PUBTIME));
                    Collections.reverse(menuItems);
                    //sortedMap = new TreeMap<Date, ArrayList>(menuItems);
                    //Log.e("SAME", "THE SAME");
                }
                //Log.e("TRIM CURR1", currDate);
                //Log.e("RSSDATE1", rssDate);
                //Log.e("TEst", "TEst");
                for (int q = 0;q < map.size();q++)
                {
                    //Log.e("mene", map.get(KEY_TITLE));
                }


                }

            }
            count+=1;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());
            }

            // Adding menuItems to ListView
            final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), menuItems,
                    R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC,KEY_LINK, KEY_TITLE }, new int[] {
                            R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.link, R.id.source});
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     setListAdapter(adapter);
                     //adapter.nnotifyDataSetChanged();
            //stuff that updates ui

                }
            });
            // selecting single ListView item


            //TextView txt = getTextView();

            //TextView firstName = (TextView) V.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

//          TextView firstName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            //ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.l)
            //ListView lv = ((ListView) findViewbyId(R.id)

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // getting values from selected ListItem
                    String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                    String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
                    String link = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.link)).getText().toString();
                    String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desciption)).getText().toString();

                    // Starting new intent
                    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
                    in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
                    in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
                    in.putExtra(KEY_LINK, link);
                    startActivity(in);

                }
            });
        }


        // mDialog.dismiss();
         Log.e("RUN", "RSSRUN");
     }

     class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

         ProgressDialog progress1 = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "dialog title",
                    "dialog message", true);

            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


                menuItems.removeAll(menuItems);
                try
                {
                rssRun();

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    menuItems.removeAll(menuItems);
                }

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                         progress1.dismiss();
                         //adapter.nnotifyDataSetChanged();
                //stuff that updates ui

                    }
                });

                return currURL;
            }


            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


            }
            protected void onPreExecute() {
            }


            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

            }    

        }


     class MapComparator implements Comparator<Map<String, String>>
     {
         private final String key;

         public MapComparator(String key)
         {
             this.key = key;
         }

         public int compare(Map<String, String> first,
                            Map<String, String> second)
         {
             // TODO: Null checking, both for maps and values
             String firstValue = first.get(key);
             String secondValue = second.get(key);
             return ((String) first.get(key)).compareTo((String) second.get(key));

         }
     }

}
```

My XML Parser class:

```
package com.example.directrssread;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.util.Log;

public class XMLParser {

    // constructor
    public XMLParser() {

    }

    /**
     * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
     * @param url string
     * */
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

    /**
     * Getting XML DOM element
     * @param XML string
     * */
    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            dbf.setCoalescing(true);   
            if (db!=null)
            {
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is); 
            }

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }

            return doc;
    }

    /** Getting node value
      * @param elem element
      */
    public final String getElementValue2( Node elem ) {  
        Node child;  
        if( elem != null){  
            if (elem.hasChildNodes()){  
                for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){  
                    //if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){  
                     if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE || child.getNodeType() == Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE  ){       
                        return child.getNodeValue();  
                    }  
                }  
            }  
        }  
        return "";  
        //return elem.getTextContent();  
    } 

     /**
      * Getting node value
      * @param Element node
      * @param key string
      * */
     public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
            NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
            return this.getElementValue2(n.item(0));
        }


}
```

The exact error message:

```
09-02 09:30:46.732: E/Error:(9578): Expected a quoted string (position:DOCDECL @1:50 in java.io.StringReader@4327b040)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the call

```
parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL[f])
```

returns null, because in a case of error it just prints the Stack trace and returns null and does not re-throw the exception. Generally it is a bad idea not to handle this error because you might, as it looks like also in this case, unexpected behavior somewhere else where it is much harder to explain.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Ah I see, so what would be the best way to handle this do you think?

Comment: @Callum: I found [this a good guide](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/04/java-exception-handling-best-practices/) 
As I could not handle the IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException or ClientProtocolException I would not catch them and just add to your function the possible exceptions.